# Angular 5 :Detect firestore document id on click event

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

The context is I am displaying the collection in a data table and I would like to get the row id to trigger a router to a detail page.I successfully retrieve the collection using, but I can't manage to get row id.

I use a click event in the row as shown below

```html
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of rows | orderBy: key : reverse | filter:filter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100, currentPage: p}" (click)="detailFunc()" [id]="row.id">
           <td>{{row.entreprise}}</td>
           <td>{{row.secteurActivite}}</td>
           <td>{{row.filiere}}</td>
           <td>{{row.departement}}</td>
           <td>{{row.proprietaire}}</td>
           <td>{{row.telephone}}</td>
           <td>{{row.email}}</td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the component attached to it

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { ExportAsConfig } from '../../services/export-as-config.model';
import { ExportAsService } from '../../services/export-as.service';
import { EconomieService } from '../../services/economie.service';
import { Ieconomie } from '../../economie';
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-economie',
  templateUrl: './economie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./economie.component.scss']
})
export class EconomieComponent{
  temp = [];
  rows = [];
  filter: string;
  @Input() id: string;

  // sort
  key: string = ''; 
  reverse: boolean = false;
  sort(key){
  this.key = key;
  this.reverse = !this.reverse;
};

// pagination indicator 
p: number = 1;

// export config section
config: ExportAsConfig = {
type: 'pdf',
elementId: "datatables",
};

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,private dataService: EconomieService,
       private exportAsService: ExportAsService,private router: Router ) { 
       this.dataService.getData().subscribe((datas) => {
         this.temp = [...datas];
         this.rows = datas;
         console.log(this.temp);
       });
  }

  exportAs(type) {
    this.config.type = type;
    this.exportAsService.save(this.config, "Liste_Elus");
    // this.exportAsService.get(this.config).subscribe(content => {
    //   this.exportAsService.download("myfile", content);
    // });
  }

  detailFunc() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dataMan', this.id]);

  }
}
```

when I tried to display the id using console.log(this.id) in the detailFunc function, it display undefined.

Any idea on the best strategy to archieve this ?

Comment: You can pass it as an argument to the event handler: `(click)="detailFunc(row.id)"`.

Comment: it works @ConnorsFan, why didn't I think about it.?

Comment: That question I cannot answer. :-) By the way, I think that you won't need to set the `id` of the row element.